# Joining Two Unique Tables with Same Column Using PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, unique

I have two tables with unique records, one for game fish (838 rows) and the other for non-game fish (140 rows). Both tables include a 'Species' column. I need to join these tables into one table where there are 978 unique rows and one Species column. I have tried LEFT JOIN, INNER JOIN, and FULL OUTER JOIN without any success. It seems simple enough, but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You want union, not join.

```
select species from game_fish_table
union all
select species from non_game_fish_table
```

Comment: This returns 7017 rows?

Comment: run each SELECT separately to confirm the row counts you quoted in your original question.  You may have multiple rows for some species that were being discarded by a DISTINCT in your original analysis. If that is the case - you could remove the ALL in the statement above so that duplicate rows will be discarded (at the cost of more computation being required by your server).

Comment: You may have to use select distinct species from as david mentions here...whatever your original query was to get to 838 rows.  I assumed they were already unique with the way your question was worded

Answer (score 1):

If your query selects similar records from both tables and they don't relate to one another by for example an ID to get information from the other table, what you want is an [UNION](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-union/):

> The UNION operator combines result sets of two or more SELECT
>   statements into a single result set.

```
SELECT species FROM gameFish
UNION
SELECT columns> ROM nonGameFish
```